# How to replace the absolute browser URL? (instead of .pushState()'s relative URL assignment)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a third party tool on my site which requires me to be in the following domain (example):

`www.bar.com`

My current location is: `www.foo.com` and I don't have access to `www.bar.com` right now. So, i used Javascript's .pushState() to assign a fake URL and make the third party tool understand that i'm on `bar`.

The problem is: if i set `window.history.pushState(null,null,"www.bar.com")` the URL becames `www.foo.com/www.bar.com"`. In other words, it sets my relative URL. I need to change my entire (absolute) URL to `www.bar.com`

Is that possible using pushState or other Javascript methods?

**Note: If some kind of JS plugin allows me to do that, i can install it too, but the initial plan is only use pure JS.**

Comment: I wonder why you need this...

Comment: Imagine the chaos that would ensue if this was possible

Comment: i'm using Google Tag Manager, which sends tracking information to Google Analytics. But I can't generate tracking information in any URL which isn't www.bar.com, otherwise it will send dummy statistics to production environment, www.bar.com is filtered, so it doesn't generate anything that could put me on trouble. I also don't have access to insert www.foo.com on the filter.

Comment: @NickZuber It wasn't even passing by my mind, lol. Really, it would be freakin' chaotic

Comment: I don't know how Google Tag Manager works, but what if you just disable its features based on the environment? if you cannot do this at client-side using javascript, all server-side solutions provides features like (rails for example) to check environment variables and such :) .. for example, I often do the "Rails.env.production?" check for inclusion of google analytics script..

Comment: @MaunoVähä It seems like a good solution, but I don't have access to change Google Analytics settings (because the filter options are set on GA, not in GTM, sorry if my explanation wasn't clear about that) . The most fast and clean solution I got is to create a personal account on both tools and test it from my account. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: **No**.

The actual domain part of the address is immutable (other than, obviously, actually redirecting to that address a la `href='http://foo.com'`). This is for security reasons: if that was possible, I could make my site take you to "facebook.com" and potentially steal account information.

Comment: Thanks! Set this one as correct because of the example given.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to completely rewrite URL

> The new URL can be any URL in the same origin as the current URL.

Answer (score 1):

To make it absolute, you should specify the scheme, e.g.

```
//www.bar.com
http://www.bar.com
https://www.bar.com
```

But of course this is blocked for security reasons. You will get an exception like

```js
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```